# Request["inputId"] not working on cshtml

Tags: razor

I have a website which has a form in it.
I am supposed to get the values from the form to put them in a database.
I am currently using razorCMS as a simple framework for my website and WEBMATRIX as the editor (i could use VS2010 but i wanna do that in webmatrix).
This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="custom">
            <fieldset title="TITLE">
                <legend>TITLE!</legend>

                <div class="five columns">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Pseudonimi" id="txtPseudo" value=""></input></div>
                <div class="columns">
                    <select style="display: none;" id="jmSex">
                        <option selected>Don't know/option>
                        <option>M</option>
                        <option>F</option>
                    </select>                        
                </div>
                <div class="columns">
                    <select style="display: none;" id="jmCat">
                        <option selected>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>                            
                    </select>                        
                </div>
                <textarea id="jmNewText" rows="6" > </textarea>
                <input class="radius button" id="btnAdd" type="Submit" title="Send" name="Dergo"
                    value="Send" style="float: right;" />
            </fieldset>
            </form>
```

After submitting my form i want to get the values using REQUEST, i am actually not getting any of the values. I get null variables all the time. I also tried to get the variables using JavaScript with document.getelementbyid(), i showes null.
This is my code on submit :

```
if (IsPost)
    {
     var pseudo = Request["txtPseudo"]; // THIS VALUE SHOWS NULL
     var content = Request["jmTextNew"];
     var kategori = Request["jmCat"];
     var sex = Request["jmSex"];   

     var db = Database.Open("razorC");
     var nextId = db.Execute("select max(id)+1 from rc_jm");
     var sqlNew = "Insert INTO rc_Jm (pseudo, id, content, creation_date, kategori, sex) "
                    + "values (@0, @4 , @1, GETDATE(), @2, @3)";
     db.Execute(sqlNew, pseudo, content, kategori, sex, nextId);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input values sent to the server identified by their `name` attribute not by the `id` attribute.

So you need to give `name` to your inputs to be able to get them from the `Request`

So

```
<input type="text" id="txtPseudo" value="">
```

should be

```
<input type="text" id="txtPseudo" name="txtPseudo" value="">
```

etc.